# Are there any way to know what bundleIDs are used within Appgroups?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, bundle-identifier, ios-app-group

I'm currently making two iOS apps(technically, a library for two apps) that uses the AppGroups that shares UserDefaults data between the apps using the same App Group ID.
The problem is I don't know how to get the bundleIDs of the apps in the AppGroups.

Background:I want to know whether the app is uninstalled or not, so decided to check the bundleIDs lists(if exists)that uses AppGroups, but haven't come across any solution after a couple of days.

Notes: I am currently building a library that controls all the appgroup information, so it would be better to have a solution without the need to configure sth in the info.plist file.

Both Objective-C and Swift solutions are fine.I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about checking the bundle IDs but if you want to check if another app is installed you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510336/programmatically-check-whether-an-app-is-installed)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've thought about this solution but unfortunately I'm building a library now to import in the app later on. Would be be nice if it there is a solution without having to edit the info.plist ...